# How use Advanced query by Oxygen builder whith ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use easy posts by oxygen builder. I'm trying to filter posts by field from the ACF.
To do this, I use Advanced Query, but I can't figure out the settings.

In image my settings, where taxonomy - field in ACF, terms - options from acf field

[image]

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [oxygen] field in the taxonomy and define which taxonomy you are trying to query. For example if you are using the built in 'Categories' use 'categories' or if you are using a custom taxonomy called use the 'custom_taxonomy'.

If you are using the built-in WP categories you may want to use category__and or category__in since its much easier. You would use a comma separated list of the category IDs.

Same applies for tags... Only if you have to mix the two (or use custom taxonomy) or require some fine tuning step up to the tax_query...